# In Flutter, how to enable and disable a button by clicking on another button?

Tags: flutter

I have two elevated buttons inside a Row widget. When I press Button 1, I want to disable Button 2 and when I press Button 1 again I want to enable Button 2. I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You just need to handle the flag for enable and disable on the click event of button 1, based on that flag have to handle the click event for button 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `onPressed : null` for disabled button 2.

Use boolean variable for set disable and enable.

```
      var isDisable=true;
```

This is the button 1 widget and it uses `setButton()` method for enable and disable button 2.

```
      //button 1
      RaisedButton( 
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.green,
          onPressed:  (){
             setState((){
               setButton();
             });
          },
          child: Text('Button 1'),
      )
```

This is the button 2 widget and we check the boolean variable ( `isDisable`) to check the enable and disable state in button 2.

```
      // button 2
      RaisedButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.green,
          onPressed:  isDisable
              ? () => null : clickButton(),
          child: Text('Button 2'),
      )
```

This is a method that uses to change boolean variable value for enable and disable button 2.

```
     //Method for enable and disable button2
     void setButton(){
       if(isDisable){
        isDisable = false;
       }else{
        isDisable = true;
       }
      
     }
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: It certainly solved my problem. Thank you.